# MySQL not saving sentence after an '

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This one has got me stumped. When I try to save something to the database that contains an apostrophe ('), it will save the sence up until then and after that it does not not. For example;

Say I am trying to save this: Report details Tim Cook's changes at Apple, for better or worse »

It saves: Report details Tim Cook

It saves to the database fine but only everything before the '

My code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
global $db, $db_table_prefix;


$origRLTitle = $_POST['RLTitle'];
$origRLURL = $_POST['RLURL'];
$origRLUserID = $_POST['user-id'];

$RLTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($origRLTitle);
$RLURL = mysql_real_escape_string($origRLURL);
$RLUserID = mysql_real_escape_string($origRLUserID);    


if(strlen($RLTitle)>0 && strlen($RLURL)>0 && strlen($RLUserID)>0)
{
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("sf") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT  INTO `ReadLater` (Title, URL, User_ID) VALUES ('".$RLTitle."', '".$RLURL."', '".$RLUserID."')");
echo "Saved";
}
}
```

Any help as to why it might not be saving properly? I have tried mysql_real_escape_string but (if I am using it correctly) that does not seem to work.

Side note: What is the best way to secure the form above from attacks?

**Update** It is also doing it for " as well.

Comment: You can use `htmlspecialchars('someValue', ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')` to escape all the quotes.

Comment: Quick question, might be utterly pointless. You aren't copy and pasting from word or anything into the Post Vars are you? Are you physically typing them in?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Have you checked if the full string is in the db and it's simply a retrieval/display problem? What's `select LENGTH(Title) ...` show?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's actually a normal `'` apostrophe as opposed to a fancy one from Word for example?

Comment: The post titles are coming in from RSS feeds so it may well be a funny character (didn't think of that). Doesn't seem to be a length issue as others are retrieved fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `mysql_real_escape_string()` *after* connecting to your database:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    global $db, $db_table_prefix;


    $origRLTitle = $_POST['RLTitle'];
    $origRLURL = $_POST['RLURL'];
    $origRLUserID = $_POST['user-id'];
    mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("sf") or die(mysql_error());

    $RLTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($origRLTitle);
    $RLURL = mysql_real_escape_string($origRLURL);
    $RLUserID = mysql_real_escape_string($origRLUserID);    


    if(strlen($RLTitle)>0 && strlen($RLURL)>0 && strlen($RLUserID)>0)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT  INTO `ReadLater` (Title, URL, User_ID) VALUES ('".$RLTitle."', '".$RLURL."', '".$RLUserID."')");
        echo "Saved";
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, but my suspicion is this is not the problem's core. It reeks more of a charset issue (with the `'` being some fancy special character rather than a normal `'`). If the string escaping were broken, he'd not have anything in his database at all

Comment: I have tried the code above and it still does not save past the ', tricky little blighter this one.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mysql_query("INSERT  INTO `ReadLater` (Title, URL, User_ID) VALUES ('".$RLTitle."', '".$RLURL."', '".$RLUserID."')");
```

to

```
$query = "INSERT  INTO `ReadLater` (Title, URL, User_ID) VALUES ('".$RLTitle."', '".$RLURL."', '".$RLUserID."')";
echo $query;
mysql_query($query);
```

And check out the actual query you are sending, easy to spot the problems then :)